# Only want filename from url in json file

Tags: json, sed, jenkins-pipeline, jq

I have the following json file below:

```
{"cloud":"https://cloudfronturl/folder/folder",
"env": "int"
"sources":["https://www.example.com/some.tar.gz","https://www.example2.com/folder1/folder2/another.tar.gz"],
"owner": "some manager"
}
```

How can I modify the file to read like below, where only the file names stripped from sources url? Don't want to touch cloud value

```
{"cloud":"https://cloudfronturl/folder/folder",
"env": "int"
"sources":["some.tar.gz","another.tar.gz"],
"owner": "some manager"
}
```

Comment: Your input JSON is not valid. Missing `,` in `env` line

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain what was wrong with it. Alternately, if you have time, you could also take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: `jq '.sources[] |= (sub(".*/";""))' Input_file`. With your shown samples, this could be also done by, using `sub` function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON snippet is fixed and using `jq` is an option, you could do

```
jq '.sources[] |= ( split("/") | last )'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{http[^"]+/}{}g' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

`http[^"]+/` : literal `http`, followed by any character *other than* `"`, repeated 1 or more times.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: looks nice, but perl won't be an option

Comment: Doesn't that also modify the `cloud` URL?